# is an unbiased estimator better than an efficient estimator?

Tags: self-study, inference

I've learnt that the efficiency of an estimator, say $\theta$, is defined by $Var(\theta)$. The closer to 0 this value is, the more efficient the estimator is.

Let's say I have two estimators: $\theta_1, \theta_2$, and I know that $\theta_1$ is an unbiased estimator, but $\theta_2$ is a biased estimator.

I also know that $\theta_2$ is more efficient than $\theta_1$.

**So, summarizing: $\theta_1$ is unbiased but it is also less efficient than $\theta_2$. $\theta_2$ is biased but it is also more efficient than $\theta_1$**

Can I conclude that $\theta_1$ is worse (or better) than $\theta_2$?

if so... which one is better?

if unbiased vs efficiency is not enough information... what can i do to see what estimator is better?

Comment: You probably need to specify the criteria that you have in mind for "better". Which is better may well depend on the purpose(s) for which they will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, for a model with a continuous response, mean squared error (MSE) can be used for evaluation.

MSE = Bias^2 + Variance

In general, a simpler model can have higher bias and lower variance. Bias gets down while variance goes up while a model becomes complicated. This is called as bias-variance tade-off. (A similar idea applies to categorical responses.)

Which is better over another pretty much depends on the aim of analysis. If interpretation is more important, simpler models would server well while complicated models, so called black-box models, would be necessary if prediction is of main interest.

Comment: so if the MSE of $\theta_1$ is smaller than the MSE of $\theta_2$, we could conclude that $\theta_1$ is better than $\theta_2$?

Comment: As Jaehyeon said "Which is better over another pretty much depends on the aim of analysis".  These things are never so clear cut.

Comment: @ Bengalaa Yes, I'd say this is a typical way of evaluating model performance (and thus estimator) for a model with a continuous response. For a categorical response, mean misclassification error can be used and it is just (# misclassification / # records).